# I can't get files that are outside my app folder Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions

I was doing a file selection window and ran into the problem that I can't get files that are outside the application folder **(com.example.kos)**, even though my application has access to work with files

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kos">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".Times"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Getting permissions**

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE},REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER_CONF);
                    }
```

Android - 10 (api 29)

UPD:
**Getting the path to app folder**

```
File currentPath = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/backups");
```

[debugging and listFiles () method show that the folder is not empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwtAT.png)

But if specify any other folder not related to my application, such as the download folder, [it immediately becomes empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irJea.png), although files are there

```
currentPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Comment: Please tell full path of that application folder. Also show the code to obtain that path.

Comment: For such application folders (yes... there is more than one) you do not need any permission.

Comment: @blackapps, I added an example to main post. As far as I understand permissions are necessary for accessing java.io.File class

Comment: Permissions have nothing to do with using the File class. Only with the used path. Below Q needed for getExternalStorageDirectory only. But the same directory is blocked under Q and R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 10 comes with Scoped storage. This is the reason why you don't see any files outside the app folder. You can [opt-out](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#maintain-compatibility-android-10) scoped storage. Just add attribute below to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application>
...
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
</application>
```

It is a solution only for compatibility with Android 10. For Android 11 you need to access files with [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider). If your app targets Android 11, check out also [theese changes](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#file-directory-restrictions) for SAF.